# Elasticsearch alphabetical desc order turkish character problems

Tags: sorting, elasticsearch, ascii

Alphabetical_desc when I want to make a sort, it first brings up the word "Pearl", and then brings up the word "Zara". My Template is as follows:

```
"analysis": {
  "filter": {
    "my_ascii_folding": {
      "type": "asciifolding",
      "preserve_original": true
    }
  },
  "analyzer": {
    "turkish_autocomplete": {
      "tokenizer": "autocomplete_tokenizer",
      "filter": [
        "lowercase",
        "my_ascii_folding"
      ]
    }
  }
```

I want it to start from Z first and be sorted. Can you help, thanks.

Comment: Can you also share your mapping and the query?

Comment: {
  "from": 0,
  "size": 10,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "adjust_pure_negative": true,
      "boost": 1
    }
  },
  "sort": [
    {
      "brandName": {
        "order": "desc"
      }
    }
  ],
  "track_total_hits": 2147483647
}

Comment: Can you also share your mapping?